# Unspecified error when opening the 65th ADODB Recordset in a loop

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I have a bit of code that loops through a bunch of files in a folder and loads the data into recordsets, storing the filenames and recordsets in a dictionary (as a key/value pair) for later use.  The loop works fine for the first 64 files, but then it gives me an "Unspecified Error" dialog on the 65th try.  The code breaks at the recordData.Open line (the loop calls the below function, so the For Each loop is not shown):

```
Public Function GetRecords(ByVal dataSrc as String) as ADODB.Recordset

Dim dir as String
Dim file as String
Dim recordData as ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql as String
Dim conn as String

dir = "C:\MyDirectory"
file = dataSrc & ".csv"

conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & dir & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;"""

If DoesFileExist(dir & file) Then
    sql = "select * from " & file & ";"

    Set recordData = New ADODB.Recordset

    recordData.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    recordData.Open sql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
Else
    Set recordData = Nothing
End If

Set GetRecords = recordData

recordData.Close

End Function
```

If I rename or delete the file it currently stops on, it errors out on the new 65th file, so I know the actual file itself is not to blame.  Is there a limitation on the number of recordsets that I can open in one session, or am I opening them in an inefficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after tinkering with it, I discovered the problem lay in the connection.  Instead of constructing the connection string as a string, I created a connection object and then closed it after opening the recordset.  Must be some kind of limitation on the number of connections that can exist in a given session.  Here is the revised function:

```
Public Function GetRecords(ByVal dataSrc as String) as ADODB.Recordset

Dim dir as String
Dim file as String
Dim recordData as ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql as String
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection

dir = "C:\MyDirectory"
file = dataSrc & ".csv"

If DoesFileExist(dir & file) Then
    sql = "select * from " & file & ";"

    Set recordData = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & dir & ";" & "Extended    Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;"""
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    recordData.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    recordData.Open sql, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    cn.Close
Else
    Set recordData = Nothing
End If

Set GetRecords = recordData

recordData.Close

End Function
```